# Liquid CSS only horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have been following on-line tutorials to create a horizontal drop-down menu navigation bar using only CSS and HTML. The tutorials have gone fine, however I would like to make my navigation bar a fluid so that it adjusts to different browser sizes while still remaining a horizontal navigation bar.

I have heard that this fluid CSS could be achieved using % and ems instead of fixed width of pixels, however my attempts to achieve this have failed. Please may anyone provide some help as to how I may achieve this fluid CSS.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Casa Magnolia Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homePage.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" align="center">
        <div id="header" align ="left">
            <?php

                include "ImageFunctions.php";//include the PHP class 

                //create an object of the class so that its methods can be accessed
                $myImageFunction = new ImageFunctions();
                $logo = $myImageFunction->logo();
                //$data= $myImageFunction->getData();

            ?>

        </div>
        <div id ="menuWrapper" align="left">
            <div id ="navMenu" align="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!-- end Home link -->
                    <li><a href="#">The House</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Slide Show</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><!-- ends the House info list -->

                    <li><a href="#">The Area</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Info about the area</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sites and Attractions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Address</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><!-- ends The Area info list -->
                    <li><a href ="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cancellation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Security Deposits</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Smoking Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pets Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Swimming Pool</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pest Control</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Complaints</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Arrival/Departure</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Codes of Conduct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Limits of Liability</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><!-- end of Terms and Conditions list --> 
                    <li><a href ="#">Book With Us</a></li><!-- end of Book with us Link -->
                    <li><a href ="#">Help</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><!-- end of Help list -->
                </ul> <!-- end main UL -->
                <br class="clearFloat" />
            </div><!-- end navMenu div -->
        </div> <!-- ends the menuWrapper div -->


    </div>
</body>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```
/* 
Document   : homePage
Created on : 16-Feb-2012, 17:00:56
Author     : gerrard
Description:
    Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/

@charset "utf-8";

#header 
{ 
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
float: top;
background-color: beige;
margin:20px;

}


#menuWrapper
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: yellow;
margin: 10px;
}


#navMenu
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
float: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#navMenu ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 30px;
}

#navMenu li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
background: orchid;
}

#navMenu ul li a
{
text-align: center;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
text-decoration: none;
height: 40%;
width: 230px;
display: block;
color: yellow;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#navMenu ul ul
{
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
top: 32px;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul
{
visibility: visible;

}




/********************************************************************************/

#navMenu li:hover
{
background: visible;   
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover
{
background: violet;
color: silver;
}

#navMenu a:hover 
{
color: peachpuff;
}

.clearFloat
{
clear: both;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.

Check out this Fiddle I made --> http://jsfiddle.net/HerrLoop/FxNsj/

The big changes were:

-removing the hardcoded width on the 'a' tags

-giving all nav li's a width of 100%

-giving all nav > ul > li (primary nav items) a width of 16% (this overrides the last point only for primary nav items)

```
#navMenu > ul > li {
width:16%;
}
```

-giving all nav ul ul a width of 100%

it's not a perfect solution, but hopefully it helps.

take care.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Media Queries to help with this, so you can get close to a fluid layout